# SQL or Subquery if possible without using functions

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a table in data base which look like this:-(orignal one contain more than a 5000 records)

```
n_event_key   n_txn_type_key      n_transaction_amount
1234               4                      6000 
1234               6                      4000
1234               6                      500 
1234               4                      600
1234               4                      200
1235               4                      3000
1235               6                      4000
1235               4                      500
1235               6                      1000
1236               4                      2000
1236               6                      2000
1237               4                      3500
1238               6                      2400
```

I want queries which give me following results

(i) n_event_key where

total(n_transaction_amount) for n_txn_type_key(4)> n_txn_type_key(6)

```
n_event_key  n_txn_type_key     total(n_transaction_amount)
1234            4                  6800
```

(ii)n_event_key

total(n_transaction_amount) for n_txn_type_key(6)> n_txn_type_key(4)

```
n_event_key  n_txn_type_key     total(n_transaction_amount)
1235            6                     5000
```

(iii)n_event_key

total(n_transaction_amount) for n_txn_type_key(4) = n_txn_type_key(6)

```
n_event_key   n_txn_type_key    total(n_transaction_amount)
1236                 4                 2000
1236                 6                 2000
```

(iv)n_event_key that exist's only for n_txn_type_key=4

```
n_event_key   n_txn_type_key      total(n_transaction_amount)
1237             4                      3500
```

(v)n_event_key that exist's only for n_txn_type_key=6

```
n_event_key   n_txn_type_key      total(n_transaction_amount)
1238              6                    2400
```

Comment: GROUP BY with SUM().

Comment: but its showing me result for both 4 and 6......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use group by and sum, but before that, you should create two subqueries according to n_txn_type_key and then compare:

```
select txn_type_4.n_event_key, txn_type_4.tran_amount from 
(
    select n_event_key, sum(n_transaction_amount) as tran_amount from TABLE_NAME where
    n_txn_type_key = 4 group by n_event_key
) txn_type_4
inner join 
(
    select n_event_key, sum(n_transaction_amount) as tran_amount from TABLE_NAME where
    n_txn_type_key = 6 group by n_event_key
) txn_type_6 on txn_type_4.n_event_key = txn_type_6.n_event_key
where txn_type_4.tran_amount > txn_type_4.tran_amount
```

This query is for n_txn_type_key(4) > n_txn_type_key(6). By changing the where clause, you can reach what you want.